# То работает, то не работает регистрация на сайте - Django

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование, регистрация, интернет-магазин

Пытаюсь сделать регистрацию в интернет-магазин с подтверждением через почту. Регистрация проходит раз через раз, но после того, как я нажимаю на "Зарегистрировать", загружается та же страница регистрации. В базу заносится новый пользователь с такими данными(при чем это срабатывает не каждый раз), но войти на сайт я уже с этими данными не могу.
Это мой первый сайт с регистрацией, поэтому сложно найти ошибку. Буду благодарна за любую помощь.

Прилагаю код:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

from django.dispatch import Signal

from .utilities import send_activation_notification

class AdvUser(AbstractUser):

    is_activated = models.BooleanField(default = True, db_index = True, 
    verbose_name = 'Активація пройдена?')
    send_messages = models.BooleanField(default = True, verbose_name = 
    'Дозвіл на відправку повідомлень про оновлення сайту')

    class Meta(AbstractUser.Meta):
        pass

    user_registrated = Signal(providing_args=['instance'])

    def user_registrated_dispatcher(sender, **kwargs):
        send_activation_notification(kwargs['instance'])

    user_registrated.connect(user_registrated_dispatcher)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import password_validation

from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

from django import forms

from .models import AdvUser


from .models import user_registrated

class RegisterUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required = True, label = 'Адреса електронної пошти')
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        label = 'Пароль', widget = forms.PasswordInput, 
        help_text = password_validation.password_validators_help_text_html()
    )
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label = 'Повторіть пароль', widget = forms.PasswordInput, 
        help_text = 'Введіть пароль повторно для підтвердження'
    )

    def clean_password1(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data['password1']
        if password1:
            password_validation.validate_password(password1)
        return password1


    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        password1 = self.cleaned_data['password1']
        password2 = self.cleaned_data['password2']
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            errors = {'password2' : ValidationError(
                'Введені паролі не співпадають', code = 'password_mismatch')}
            raise ValidationError(errors)



    def save(self, commit = True):
        user = super().save(commit = False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])
        user.is_active = False
        user.is_activated = False
        if commit:
            user.save()
        user_registrated.send(RegisterUserForm, instance = user)
        return user

    class Meta:
        model = AdvUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'first_name', 
        'last_name', 'send_messages')
```

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import RegisterUserForm
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from .models import AdvUser
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.core.signing import BadSignature
from .utilities import signer


@login_required
def profile(request):
    return render(request, 'registration/profile.html')


class Login_signinLoginView(LoginView):
    template_name = 'registration/registration.html'

class Login_signinLogoutView(LoginRequiredMixin, LogoutView):
    template_name = 'registration/logout.html'


class RegisterUserView(CreateView):
    model = AdvUser
    template_name = 'registration/registration.html'
    success_url = '/accounts/register/done/'
    form_class = RegisterUserForm

    class RegisterDoneView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'registration/register_done.html'

    def user_activate(request, sign):
        try:
            username = signer.unsign(sign)
        except BadSignature:
            return render(request, 'registration/bad_signature.html')
        user = get_object_or_404(AdvUser, username=username)
        if user.is_activated:
            template = 'registration/user_is_activated.html'
        else:
            template = 'registration/activation_done.html'
            user.is_active = True
            user.is_activated = True
            user.save()
        return render(request, template)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from django.conf.urls import include
from .views import Login_signinLoginView, Login_signinLogoutView
from .views import profile
from .views import RegisterUserView, RegisterDoneView
from .views import user_activate


urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/login/', Login_signinLoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('accounts/logout/', Login_signinLogoutView.as_view(), name = 'logout'),
    path('accounts/register/', RegisterUserView.as_view(), name = 'register'),
    path('accounts/register/done/', RegisterDoneView.as_view(), name = 'register_done'),
    path('account/register/activate/<str:sign>/', user_activate, name = 'register_activate'),
    path('/mainpage/', include('mainpage.urls')),
    path('accounts/profile/', profile, name = 'profile')
]
```

**utilities.py**

```
from django.core.signing import Signer
from dnipromuch.settings import ALLOWED_HOSTS
from django.template.loader import render_to_string


signer = Signer()

def send_activation_notification(user):
    if ALLOWED_HOSTS:
        host = 'http://' + ALLOWED_HOSTS[0]
    else:
        host = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
    context = {'user': user, 'host': host, 'sign': 
    signer.sign(user.username)}
    subject = render_to_string('email/activation_letter_subject.txt', 
        context)
    body_text = render_to_string('email/activation_letter_body.txt', context)
    user.email_user(subject, body_text)
```

Comment: Неплохо для начинающей. А как вы пользователя активируете? Через `RegisterDoneView`?

Comment: @digital-mag, Да, через RegisterDoneView. После регистрации пользователю должна открыться страница по ссылке accounts/register/done, на ней сказано, что отправлено письмо с ссылкой активации на почту.

Comment: @Charlie, по ссылке с письма вы переходите по ссылке во вью user_activate и активируете пользователя, если он не активен. Вы уверены, что пользователь уже активирован на момент авторизации (тот пользователь, под чьим ником вы не можете зайти)?

Comment: @Александр, он не активирован, скорее всего, потому что сама активация не состоялась. Но я просто решила проверить, смогу ли я войти на сайт с его данными, если этот пользователь появился в базе.

Comment: Если вы используете механизм LoginView, то вы не сможете авторизовать неактивированную учётную запись. Так задумано создателями Джанго

Comment: @Александр, я поняла это, спасибо. Но почему не идет активация, вы не можете увидеть это в коде? Какие ошибки я допустила?

Comment: @Charlie, первое, с чего бы я начал - это переходите ли вы по ссылке `register_activate` в принципе? Правильный ли username передается? И когда переходите, то нет ли ошибок?

Comment: @Александр, возможно, что до register_activate не доходит, и в этом и проблема.По-крайней мере, страница активации не загружается.  Проверяла, ошибки при отправке запроса, username передается тот, который введен с клавиатуры.

Comment: @Charlie, ошибка `BadSignature`?

Comment: @Александр, нет. Ошибок при отправке запроса нет вообще. Все проходит, но перенаправление  на succes_url, которое должно задействовать активацию, не происходит. И BadSignature тоже не срабатывает.

Comment: Судя по всему, неверно формируется url в теле письма. Вы передаёте в контексте строку username и с сигнатурой через двоеточие. Полагаю, вы всю ее вставляете в url. В итоге получаем невалидный http, тк в url все что идёт после двоеточия интерпретируется как порт. А сигнатура - не порт

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего Вы изучаете Джанго по книге Дронова forms.py работает не верно в примере из книги, если пароль1 не проходит валидацию то он не возвращается, пользователь создан, но не отправлено письмо для активации, если вводите хороший пароль то все работает. Я исправил этот момент так и все заработало как следует:

```
def clean_password1(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data['password1']
        """добавлено самостоятельно исключена ошибка KeyError
        оригинал    if password1:
                        password_validation.validate_password(password1)
                    return password1
        выдавал ошибку KeyError, не возвращал password1
        в строку    super().clean()
                    password1 = self.cleaned_data['password1'] """ 
        try:
            password_validation.validate_password(password1)
        except forms.ValidationError as error:
            self.add_error('password1', error)
        return password1
    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        password1 = self.cleaned_data['password1']
        password2 = self.cleaned_data['password2']
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            errors = {'password2': ValidationError(
            'ВВеденные пароли не совпадают', code='password_mismath' )}
            raise ValidationError(errors)
```